# applying a function to combinations of groups, holding 1 group fixed

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like:

```
   grp    date                id              Y
   <chr>  <dttm>              <chr>       <dbl>
 1 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 04003      17039.
 2 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 04006      13233.
 3 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 04011_AM    7918.
 4 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 0401301_AD 22586.
 5 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 0401303    20527.
 6 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 0401305    29422.
 7 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22017_AM    7088.
 8 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22021_AM    8134.
 9 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22039_AM   15842.
10 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22048      16142.
```

Which has different groups. I also have a function:

```
normaliseData <-function(m){
  (m - min(m)) / (max(m) - min(m))
}
```

I want to normalise the groups by the min and max of the pairwise values, holding `group1` fixed. That is, I want to normalise the data fixing `group1` so it will have the following combinations.

- `group1` & `group2`
- `group1` & `group3`
- `group1` & `group4`

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(grp = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", 
"group2", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", 
"group4", "group4", "group4", "group4", "group4", "group4"), 
    date = structure(c(1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), id = c("04003", 
    "04006", "04011_AM", "0401301_AD", "0401303", "0401305", 
    "22017_AM", "22021_AM", "22039_AM", "22048", "22053_AM", 
    "22054_AM", "28002", "28004", "2800501", "2800502", "2800503", 
    "2800504", "31010_AM", "31015_AM", "31016", "31019_AM", "31023", 
    "31029_AM"), Y = c(17039.329, 13232.982, 7917.693, 22585.676, 
    20527.113, 29422.471, 7087.536, 8134.265, 15842.035, 16142.111, 
    11493.981, 6556.387, 22086.768, 11325.882, 53449.067, 83662.101, 
    78508.089, 66107.125, 5095.169, 5590.531, 17796.439, 6028.701, 
    39271.698, 3642.281)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    grp = c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:6, 7:12, 13:18, 19:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

I am looking to apply the following:

```
#Min / max from group1 and group2
    data %>% 
      filter(grp == "group1" | grp == "group2") %>% 
      mutate(
        normedOut = normaliseData(Y)
      )

#Min / max from group1 and group3
    data %>% 
      filter(grp == "group1" | grp == "group3") %>% 
      mutate(
        normedOut = normaliseData(Y)
      )

#Min / max from group1 and group4
    data %>% 
      filter(grp == "group1" | grp == "group4") %>% 
      mutate(
        normedOut = normaliseData(Y)
      )
```

Comment: To clarify what you want for your desired output, if you wanted to normalize Y for groups 1 + 2, is that (m - min(group2))/(max(group2) - min(group2))

Comment: I added a small edit with some code to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Comment: That's not desired output, I think that's attempted code. Your three code blocks all write to `normedOut`, do you intend to use these three frames independently? Is there a problem with it? Are you instead intending to add three columns, one for each pair of groups?

Comment: The code I gave does not generalise to more groups. I plan on running some regressions on the grouped data. My original idea was to have them all in the same column.

Comment: Okay, I see a problem. Row 1 is associated with `group1`. You want a new column that represents normalized data between `group` and `group2`, that's fine, that can go on that row. But where to you put the value for `Y` that is normalized between `group1` and `group3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `purrr` based on what I understand from your question. We create a vector, `groups`, that contains the groups we are interested in looping over for our three pairs holding group1 fixed. We use your desired filter and mutate sequence and then create columns named for each group in our `groups` vector that contains the normalized data. This will result in a dataframe that contains 3 new columns, each column representing the normalized Y between group 1 and another group. NAs will populate where there is no pair (e.g. between group2 and group3)

```
groups <- c("group2", "group3", "group4")
groups %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(~ data %>%
        filter(grp == "group1" | grp == .x) %>%
        mutate(!!.x := normaliseData(Y)))
```