# applying a regression model to each column using mutate across

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a follow on question to one I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565164/applying-a-function-to-combinations-of-groups-holding-1-group-fixed?noredirect=1#comment115921094_65565164)

The solution was to use the following code:

```
groups <- c("group2", "group3", "group4")
dataGroups <- groups %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(~ data %>%
        filter(grp == "group1" | grp == .x) %>%
        mutate(!!.x := normaliseData(Y)))
```

Using this, I now have a data frame which looks like:

```
   grp    date                id              Y group2 group3 group4
   <chr>  <dttm>              <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 04003      17039. 0.424      NA     NA
 2 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 04006      13233. 0.247      NA     NA
 3 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 04011_AM    7918. 0          NA     NA
 4 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 0401301_AD 22586. 0.682      NA     NA
 5 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 0401303    20527. 0.586      NA     NA
 6 group1 2020-09-01 00:00:00 0401305    29422. 1          NA     NA
 7 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22017_AM    7088. 0.0554     NA     NA
 8 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22021_AM    8134. 0.165      NA     NA
 9 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22039_AM   15842. 0.969      NA     NA
10 group2 2020-09-01 00:00:00 22048      16142. 1          NA     NA
```

I now want to mutate across the columns and apply a linear regression model. I can generate the data using:

```
dataGroups2 <- dataGroups %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    control = sample(c(0,1), 1),
    treatment = ifelse(grp == "group1", 1, 0),
    did = control * treatment
    )
```

But I cannot apply my regression model over the columns.

```
dataGroups2 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(.) %in% groups),  ~lm(log(.x) ~ treatment + control + did ))
```

The only thing which changes is the `Y` variable. How can I map over the columns and run the regression model?

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(grp = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", 
"group2", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", 
"group4", "group4", "group4", "group4", "group4", "group4"), 
    date = structure(c(1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 
    1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1598918400
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), id = c("04003", 
    "04006", "04011_AM", "0401301_AD", "0401303", "0401305", 
    "22017_AM", "22021_AM", "22039_AM", "22048", "22053_AM", 
    "22054_AM", "28002", "28004", "2800501", "2800502", "2800503", 
    "2800504", "31010_AM", "31015_AM", "31016", "31019_AM", "31023", 
    "31029_AM"), Y = c(17039.329, 13232.982, 7917.693, 22585.676, 
    20527.113, 29422.471, 7087.536, 8134.265, 15842.035, 16142.111, 
    11493.981, 6556.387, 22086.768, 11325.882, 53449.067, 83662.101, 
    78508.089, 66107.125, 5095.169, 5590.531, 17796.439, 6028.701, 
    39271.698, 3642.281)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    grp = c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:6, 7:12, 13:18, 19:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

I can individually run the regressions:

```
dataGroups2 %>% 
  lm(group2 ~ control + did + treatment + did, data = .) %>% 
  summary()

dataGroups2 %>% 
  lm(group3 ~ control + did + treatment + did, data = .) %>% 
  summary()

dataGroups2 %>% 
  lm(group4 ~ control + did + treatment + did, data = .) %>% 
  summary()
```

The only thing which is changing is the `Y` variable.

EDIT:

Tidy solution:

```
linearRegFunction <- function(x){
  lm(get(x) ~ control + did + treatment, data = dataGroups)
}

groups %>% 
  map(., ~linearRegFunction(.x))
```

Comment: what do you want your final ouput to be? do you  want to change the outcome for each model and still have the same 3 predictors for each variable?

Comment: Bit confused... Is this what you want to do? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88508/applying-linear-regression-to-a-data-subset

Comment: I would like to run the regression for each `groupX` column. I have added an edit with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While one could certainly come up with a `tidyverse` solution using `broom` or `purrr`, sometimes a simple solution has its beauty, too. E.g.:

```r
lapply(groups, function(x) summary(lm(get(x) ~ control + did + treatment, data=dataGroups2)))
```